# How to function dispatch_group?

Tags: objective-c

I am using dispatch_group in my code, but it's functionality not cleared to me.

I have used below code:

```
1.dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
2.dispatch_group_enter(group);
3.[self exportVideoAsset:avAsset withRange:CMTimeRangeMake(start1, duration1) inGCDGroup:group];

4.dispatch_group_enter(group);
5.[self exportVideoAsset:avAsset withRange:CMTimeRangeMake(start2, duration2) inGCDGroup:group];
```

Here 2 and 4 line execute first and then execute exportVideoAsset function in line 3 and 5. But here in 3 and 5 line, function exportVideoAsset is execute without no sequential order. But I want exportVideoAsset function in line 3 will always execute first, then execute line 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it always call block1 first then after call block2.

Working fine on Xcode 11, iOS13

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
    // block1
    NSLog(@"Block1");
});

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
    // block2
    NSLog(@"Block2");
});
```

or

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
    // Task is completed, so signal that it has finished
    NSLog(@"Block1");
    dispatch_group_leave(group);

// Make the second task wait until group1 has completed before running
dispatch_group_enter(group);
    // Task is completed, so signal that it has finished
    NSLog(@"Block2");
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
```